# many selects (dropdowns) on html form, how to get just the value of the select that was changed

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, cgi

In a python cgi script I have many selects in a form (100 or so), and each select has 5 or 6 options to choose from.  I don't want to have a separate submit button, so I am using `onchange="submit();"` to submit the form as soon as an option is selected from one of the many selects.  When I read the form data with  `form.keys()` the name of every select on the form is listed instead of just the one that was changed.  This requires me to compare the value selected in each select with the starting value to find out which one changed and this of course is very slow.  How can I just get the new value of the one select that was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every `select` should be the only value that's needed, then every select is basically a `form` on its own.

You could either remove all other `select`s when you activate a single select (which is prone to errors), or simply put every select in its own `form` instead of using one giant `form`. Otherwise all data is going to be send.

Comment: I thought about creating a form for every select before I asked the question but then chickened out because I had my doubts about it working.  Gave it a try, and it works great. Thanks